# Element-wise division with accumulated numbers in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

The title may come across as confusing (honestly, not quite sure how to summarize it in a sentence), so here is a much better explanation:

I'm currently handling a dataFrame *A* regarding different attributes, and I used a `.groupby[].count()` function on a data column `age` to create a list of occurrences:

```
A_sub = A.groupby(['age'])['age'].count()
```

`A_sub` returns a Series similar to the following (the values are randomly modified):

```
age
1    316
2    249
3    221
4    219
5    262
...
59    1
61    2
65    1
70    1
80    1
Name: age, dtype: int64
```

I would like to plot a list of values from element-wise division. The division I would like to perform is an element value divided by the sum of all the elements that has the index greater than or equal to that element. In other words, for example, for age of 3, it should return

```
221/(221+219+262+...+1+2+1+1+1)
```

The same calculation should apply to all the elements. Ideally, the outcome should be in the similar type/format so that it can be plotted.

Comment: I am not very used to pandas and series, but in numpy, which is fairly close, you could start by computing the vector of the coefficients by which you want to divide each element, and then divide element-wise your age counter by those coefficients.

Comment: Hi @Mathieu do you mind demonstrating the procedure a bit? Not quite sure I follow, as I am not very used to doing this in numpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick example using numpy. A similar approach can be used with pandas. The `for` loop can most likely be replaced by something smarter and more efficient to compute the coefficients.

```
import numpy as np

ages = np.asarray([316, 249, 221, 219, 262])
coefficients = np.zeros(ages.shape)

for k, a in enumerate(ages):
    coefficients[k] = sum(ages[k:])

output = ages / coefficients
```

Output:

```
array([0.24940805, 0.26182965, 0.31481481, 0.45530146, 1.        ])
```

**EDIT:** The coefficients initizaliation at `0` and the `for` loop can be replaced with:

```
coefficients = np.flip(np.cumsum(np.flip(ages)))
```

Comment: Thanks Mathieu! What I might do then is simply `np.asarray(A_sub)`. My one concern is that this method neglects the ages with no value (e.g. age 60 would be skipped from the array). Is it possible to have ages with no value to have a value of 0? Hence, ages like 60, 62, 63, 64, 66,... would all have a numerical value of 0, and therefore would affect the outcome (in terms of number of elements).

Comment: @Robin Of course it is possible, but how do you want to take into account the ages with 0? Take them out? At the moment, it's ding exactly what you described in your post. Could you make an example of your expected output for `[316, 249, 221, 219, 0, 262, 0]` (0 for 5 and 7).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `cumsum()` in pandas to get accumulated sums:

```
A_sub = A['age'].value_counts().sort_index(ascending=False)
(A_sub / A_sub.cumsum()).iloc[::-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

No reason to use numpy, pandas already includes everything we need.

`A_sub` seems to return a Series where `age` is the index. That's not ideal, but it should be fine. The code below therefore operates on a series, but can easily be modified to work DataFrames.

```py
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(data=np.random.randint(low=1, high=10, size=10), index=[0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13], name="age")
print(s)

res = s / s[::-1].cumsum()[::-1]
res = res.rename("cumsum div")
```

I saw your comment about missing ages in the index. Here is how you would add the missing indexes in the range from min to max index, and then perform the division.

```py
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(data=np.random.randint(low=1, high=10, size=10), index=[0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13], name="age")

s_all_idx = s.reindex(index=range(s.index.min(), s.index.max() + 1), fill_value=0)
print(s_all_idx)

res = s_all_idx / s_all_idx[::-1].cumsum()[::-1]
res = res.rename("all idx cumsum div")
```

Comment: If you downvote other answers please explain in comments so we can improve our solutions. I got my downvote at the same time as you posted your answer. What is about you @Mathieu?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to post a comment to explain! I downvoted your answer because it doesn't seem to produce the correct output. Now that you've mentioned it, i'm curious as to why my answer was downvoted.

Comment: @MykolaZotko Got one as well, dunno if it was at the same time, but still without comment :(